# dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Tags: updates, dpkg

I got this error while installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

So I ran that in terminal:

```
vennesa@vennesa-ThinkPad-R61:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.126) ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.270.orig.tar.gz
```

Since then I can't install any thing. What do I do?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I had faced same issue earlier. I simply disconnected from network.lol

Answer (score 5):

I find out an easy way, if `sudo dpkg --configure -a` wasting so much of time in installing your file just give abort the process and give `sudo dpkg --remove -a` it will remove all the uninstalled files and if you want you can install it again by giving `sudo apt-get install your_soft_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Upon returning to installing Gnome via `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, that was cut off by a power outage and I experienced exactly this issue.

I chose to issue the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then lost my terminal window forever in Windows Hyper-V 2012 manager. I was able to connect to my Linux box using SSH (PuTTY) from my Windows 7 Pro client though no problem.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot I got a satisfactory result:

I found some places saying to run commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But none of those above worked.

The solution that worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

Hope I have helped.

Comment: This worked for me in the case where the problem was a full disk, whereas `dpkg --configure -a` would just complain about that same problem without fixing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you believe the terminal is freezing/not working once that `flasplugin-installer:` line appears.

However, Adobe Flash is a proprietary program with a license that doesn't allow direct distributing by Ubuntu. Because of this, flash updates using the `flashplugin-installer`, which downloads and installs the latest version of flash onto your computer.

So, when you see this line, and it doesn't appear to be doing anything, the terminal is actually downloading the latest version of flash flash. Wait a while, and it should continue.

Comment: You can also run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`. Some time ago the installation of that package fail to me. The download did finish correctly and the flash doesn't downloaded altogether. Reinstall was the solution for me.