# trouble in dpkg says no space left on device

Tags: dpkg

"
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
"
 then it say no space left on device, and when ever I try another thing, it return same problem

Comment: Did you try deleting some unwanted packages to create some space, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your free disk space with `df` in a terminal or terminal emulator. If your disk Use% is full (above 90-95%) then you need to remove some packages or upgrade to a bigger hard drive.

Comment: it says:Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8       18273204 16613040    743380  96% /
udev             1801900        4   1801896   1% /dev
tmpfs             723688      880    722808   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1809212     2264   1806948   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7       24489984   299520  24190464   2% /media/DISK2_VOL4
/dev/sda6       48817600  2248832  46568768   5% /media/DISK2_VOL3
/dev/sda5       39060480  4720864  34339616  13% /media/DISK2_VOL2
/dev/sda1       19535008  9247252  10287756  48% /medi

Comment: this one, how to delete in there,  /dev/sda8 18273204 16613040 743380 96%

Comment: I solved the trouble, it was cause the Inodes was on 100% used on the root.

I deleted the old Linux kernels, this reduced it to 30% so now all work again.

Comment: +1, nice work, df is the number one tool to get you headed in the right direction when you're having space issues! Glad to help. If my answer helped lead to your solution, please select it as the best answer with the checkmark next to it. Enjoy open source freedom my friend!

Comment: You can't remove packages if you need to run `dpkg --configure -a` first...

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with the same initial symptoms, but the accepted answer did not work for me, as I can not (neatly) remove packages as long as the only thing the package manager does is to ask me to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` even though running this any number of times did not change anything.

#### `--pending` instead of `-a`

For a reason unknown to me – according to the manpage, they should be equivalent – `sudo dpkg --configure --pending`, as recommended in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133091/586076) to [dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.](https://askubuntu.com/q/257446/348964) solved the problem for me.

Comment: The OP's issue was clearly a ***lack of disk space***, which could be solved by deleting *any* files (in the OP's case, old kernel files), not only by cleaning up unused, or pending, packages - which, again, in the OP's case, probably wouldn't have worked, due to the lack of disk space.

Comment: @Greenonline And a specific solution that helps precisely the person who happened to ask the question first helps people having the same question for different underlying reasons how exactly? This is still a valid answer to the question posted, verbatim. My problem was also a ***lack of disk space*** so I definitely don't know why we need to shout that …

Comment: No one is shouting... emphasising maybe, but not shouting. Nevertheless, if you think that, then why did you shout "`--pending` instead of `-a`"? :-)

Comment: Well, I'll disagree with your choice of bold+italics for emphasis then when italics would have been enough, but okay, it was not my intention to derail this into a typography discussion, mea culpa.

And I marked up the heading as a heading because I'm of the opinion that it (a) is such semantically and (b) should be easily discernible for any reader skimming the answers.

I still don't see how in your initial comment (paraphrased) “The OP had the same problem as you and yours is not the only answer that worked in that one case.” constitutes a helpful comment for me or anyone else.